# Javascript table child not showing as undefined?

Tags: javascript

We have a script below where it add rows dynamically. In the addRow function we have this code alert(newcell.childNodes[0].type); to capture the childnode type. It only show the first column as checkbox but all the rest is shown as undefined. In addition for the 4th column we have more then one child node that one button and also a table in it? So how to know their types?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                newcell.innerHTML = newcell.innerHTML;
                alert(newcell.childNodes[0].type);

        }
     }

        function addSubRow2(subtbl){
            var table = document.getElementById(subtbl);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      var a=document.getElementById(subtbl).insertRow(rowCount); 
          var b=a.insertCell(0); 
          var c=a.insertCell(1); 
          b.innerHTML="TEST"; 
          c.innerHTML="<p class=error id='slaveIDError'>"; 


      /* var dropdown="<SELECT class=\"select\" name=\"country\">\n" +
                "<OPTION value=\"1\">Serial 1<\/OPTION>\n" +
                "<OPTION value=\"2\">Serial 2<\/OPTION>\n" +
                "<OPTION value=\"3\">Serial 3<\/OPTION>\n" + 
                "<OPTION value=\"4\">Serial 4<\/OPTION>" +
                "<OPTION value=\"5\">Serial 5<\/OPTION>" + 
                "<\/SELECT>";
       */


        //cell.innerHTML += "<br\/ >" + dropdown;
    }


        function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    if(rowCount <= 1) {
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


            }
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
                  row.id="row"+i;
               //iterate through rows
               //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
               for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                 //iterate through columns
                 //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
                 //alert("J : "+j);
                 col.id="col"+i;
                 if(j==0)
                 {

                 }
                 else if(j==1)
                 {

                }
               }  
            }

            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
  Begin Location : <select class='select' id="beginLocation" name="beginLocation">
                    <option value="1">Loc 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Loc 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Loc 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Loc 4</option>
                    <option value="5">Loc 5</option>
                </select>
                <p type="text" class=error id='beginLocation_Error'>
    <br\>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

    <table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Client</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Serial</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="col_0_0"><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
            <td id="col_0_1">
                <select class='select' id="client1" name="client1">
                    <option value="1">Client 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Client 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Client 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Client 4</option>
                    <option value="5">Client 5</option>
                </select><p type="text" class=error id='client_0_Error'>                
            </td>

            <td id="col_0_1">
                <select class='select' id="location1" name="location1">
                  <option value="1">Loc 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Loc 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Loc 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Loc 4</option>
                    <option value="5">Loc 5</option>
                </select>
                <p type="text" class=error id='beginLocation_Error'>                
            </td>

            <td id="col_0_3">
                <input type="button" value="Add Serial" onclick="addSubRow2('sub0');" />
                <br\>
                <table id="sub0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select class='select' id="serial_0_1" name="serial_0_1">
                                <option value="1">Serial 1</option>
                                <option value="2">Serial 2</option>
                                <option value="3">Serial 3</option>
                                <option value="4">Serial 4</option>
                                <option value="5">Serial 5</option>
                            </select>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                         <input type="text" id="txt_0_1" name="txt_0_1">                        
                       </td>
                       <td>
                         <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeSubRow2(this.parentNode);" />                       
                       </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                     <p  class=error id="selecterror_0_1">
                    </td>
                     <td>
                     <p class=error id="inputerror_0_1">
                    </td>   
                    <td>

                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Code to update row and column id

```
var rows = table.querySelectorAll('[id^=row]');
          for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
                  row.id="row"+i;
                  row.name="row"+i;
                  var rowName = "row"+i;
                  for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                     col.id="col_"+i+"_"+j;
                     col.name="col_"+i+"_"+j;

                     if(j==3)
                     {
                        alert(col.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName('button')[0]);

                     }
              }
```

Answer (score 2):

`childNodes` property includes text nodes, so by doing `newcell.childNodes[0]` you are referring to the white space before the `select` element.

Instead, you should do like this:

```
newcell.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[0]
```

or

```
newcell.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
```

Comment: I dont get you well but then why the checkbox is showing without the white space problem? My issue here is that for each of the row I want to change the name and id of the newly added select and also the inner table id in 4th column and also all its elements such as the select,input text and also the remove button? How is this possible ya?

Comment: As each of the row or serial in each cell is added or remove I need to rename and change the id accordingly? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: You simply remove the spaces from this part `<td>     <select ...`, make it like `<td><select ...`, then `newcell.childNodes[0]` will work.

Comment: How about re-name and put all the new id to all the elements each there is a new row added or deleted?

Comment: @user132638—some browsers add an empty text node to maintain white space in the DOM but don't show it, others remove such white space. You can't tell the difference by just looking at it (that's deliberate), you have to use a tool like a DOM inspector.

Comment: @RobG ok I will follow your advice so my next challenge renaming and re-id on every add or remove of the rows or even the sub table in 4th column here is my biggest problem.

Comment: @user132638—yes, that's always an issue with cloned elements (dynamically attached listeners are removed too, unless `attachEvent` was used, but that happens with innerHTML also). Names don't have to be unique and are required for form controls you want submitted. You may be able to deal with that at the sever. Avoid IDs on cloned elements if at all possible, form controls don't need them, it will make life much easier.

Comment: @RobG I have update with the codes to update the row id and col id. The issue how is on the updates of the select for each column and how to update the id of the inner table in 4th column and all the select,input and also remove button with the listeners too? I know is complex right?

Comment: @RobG What is your best idea to resolve this for both validation and also passing over the data into php?

Comment: @timidboy for this newcell.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[0] statement what does the last [0] represent because I tried it gives me error not recongise getElementsByTagName?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` return a collection (like an array) of elements, `[0]` returns the first element.

Comment: @timidboy for instance the 4th column I want to get all the content it the button and also the sub table how to go about with that?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the language attribute for script elements was deprecated in HTML 4 and is removed in HTML5. The type attribute is required.

In your code:

```
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
```

There is no need to add an argument, no argument will add the row to the end of the table. Such operations are usually faster if the node is appended to the DOM after all modification is complete.

```
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
            newcell.innerHTML = newcell.innerHTML;
            alert(newcell.childNodes[0].type);

    }
 }
```

If you are just creating a clone of an existing row, then all of the above can be replaced with something like:

```
// Get the first tbody
var tbody = table.tbodies[0];

// Clone the second row
var newRow = tbody.rows[1].cloneNode(true);

/*
   Do whatever with newRow, like change element names and IDs to 
   suitble values
*/

tbody.appendChild(newRow);
```

Note that if you put your header rows in a table head section, you can clone the first row of the tbody (i.e. table.tbody[0].rows[0]), but always add rows to the tBody because older versions of IE will barf if you append to the table.  `insertRow` avoids that but it's slow.

When deleting rows, you can do something like:

```
        var i = table.rows.length;
        var chkbox;

        while (i--) { 
            chkbox = table.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

            if (chkbox && chkbox.checked) {
                if (table.rows.length < 1) { 

                    /* error */

                } else {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: appreciate your help. My biggest issue is that each time I add a new row or delete I need to update on the name and id else I will have problem in validation and also picking up the values in php later. The complex part is that in 4th column I go another subtable in it where I can add more rows just in that cells. How can you help me on this?